# How to allow url in express params array in node.js?

Tags: node.js

This may be a somewhat stupid question but how would I pass a url into express url params array. When I try a youtube link half of it is cut off. For example 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iik25wqIuFo' comes out as 'https://www.youtube.com/watch'. Thanks for any help. Heres my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const url = require('url'); 

const app = express();

const fs = require('fs')
const youtubedl = require('youtube-dl')

function downloadvideo(link) {
  const video = youtubedl(link,
  ['--format=18'],
  { cwd: __dirname })
  video.on('info', function(info) {
    console.log('Download started')
    console.log('filename: ' + info._filename)
    console.log('size: ' + info.size)
  })
  video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myvideo.mp4'))
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello Express app!');
});

app.get('/download/video/:id', function (req, res) {
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  res.send('Downloading ' + req.params.id);
});

app.get('/download/subtitle/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});

app.get('/download/playlist/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass in text with special characters like `?`, you must first run it through a function like `encodeURIComponent()` which essentially makes these special characters' URL safe. So first step is to make the parameter URL safe by running it through `encodeURIComponent()` (or you could escape special characters manually which is not fun):

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iik25wqIuFo'));
// result: "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Diik25wqIuFo"
```

Then pass it into your URL as a query parameter.

```
yourAppUrl.com/path?youtubeLink=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Diik25wqIuFo
```